# Qual o melhor método para fazer autenticação de login em android e webservice php RESTFul?

Tags: php, android, web-service, restful, slim

Estou construindo uma aplicação que necessita de login, já criei o webservice em php usando Slim.

Atualmente estou usando um POST, passando um json com e-mail e senha para o webservice retornar o json do usuário correspondente, mas acredito que não seja a melhor forma.

Se puderem me sugerir um jeito melhor utilizando essas tecnologias.

Obrigado.

Comment: convem pelo menos, usar um encode e mandar uma string e nao o email e palavra chave como plain text...

Comment: Veja o retrofit segue o site da biblioteca http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: poste o código para que possamos analisar e sugerir mudanças.

Comment: Fazer um encode da sua string antes de enviar não vai resolver nada, o código estará no lado do cliente, basta inspecionar. Não há problema desde que você utilize o POST e uma conexão segura (https) para enviar os dados de login. Facebook, Twitter, etc... que utilizam o protocolo HTTP para fazer autenticação funcionam assim.

Comment: Olha eu acho que você poderia fazer essa verificação por get que é um tipo de request mais rápido e simples, já que é apenas para validar email e senha, use o Get. Obs: Lembre-se de encriptar o email e senha antes de enviar ao servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Para fazer a verificação você pode sim enviar as credenciais do usuário como está fazendo(tem que ser https), e como você vai usar em mobile, acredito que seja mais apropriado trabalhar com JSON Web Tokens(JWT) para o retorno!

[JWT](https://jwt.io/)

Você retorna um token para o usuário, guarda este Token e em toda request que o usuário fizer esse token ira junto. Desta forma, você poderá validar o token no seu servidor e continuar com a ação caso seja válido ou simplesmente negar o token por já ter expirado ou inválido.